# Linux BC: Decimal/Floating Calculation NOT Accurate

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, command-line, 32-bit

I am writing a command line program in BASH on Ubuntu 10.08.

However, I found one problem:

```
VSize=`echo 370.02 \* 1024 \* 1024 |bc`
echo ${VSize}
387994091.52
```

**However, 370.02 * 1 024 * 1 024 = 387994092**

I have Python 2.6 installed, even python says:

```
print 370.02*1024*1024
387994091.52
```

How can I get the accurate answer in Linux command line?

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> **However, 370.02 * 1 024 * 1 024 = 387994092**

Not quite.

```
>>> 387994092. / 1024 / 1024
370.02000045776367
>>> 0.00000045776367 * 1024 * 1024
0.47999999803392002
```

The inaccurate one is you.

Comment: Ah...The inaccurate one is Google. Type `370.02*1024*1024` into Google and you get: `370.02 * 1 024 * 1 024 = 387 994 092`. I trust Google too much.